# Dockerize django app along side with cucumber test

Tags: django, docker, cucumber

Here is the case. I have simple django app with cucumber tests. I dockerized the django app and  it works perfect, but I want to dockerize the cucumber test too and run them.  Here is my project sturcutre:

```
-cucumber_drf_tests
   -feature
   -step_definitions
   axiosinst.js
   config.js
   package.json
   cucumber.js
   Dockerfile
   package-lock.json
-project_apps  
-common
docker-compose.yaml
Dockerfile
manage.py
requirements.txt
```

Here is my cucumber_drf_tests/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app/src

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["yarn", "cucumber-drf"] (this is how I run my test locally)
```

My second Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN mkdir -p /app/src

WORKDIR /app/src

COPY requirements.txt /app/src

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/src
```

And my docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  test:
    build: ./cucumber_drf_tests
    image: cucumber_test
    container_name: cucumber_container
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - app
  app:
    build: .
    image: app:django
    container_name: django_rest_container
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
    - .:/django #describes a folder that resides on our OS within the container
    command: >
      bash -c "python manage.py migrate
      && python manage.py loaddata ./project_apps/fixtures/dummy_data.json
      && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres_db
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=bla
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=blaa
```

If I remove I remove test service and run the tests locally everything is fine, but otherwise I got different errors the last one is:

```
Bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated
```

It is logic I know, but how to tell to test_container to make the API calls to the address of the running django_rest_container. Maybe this dummy question but I am new of containers world so every sharing of good practice is wellcomed

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in exposing the ports. You are exposing both app and test on the same port (8000). For container you can keep it same. But for host it has to be different.

```
<host port> : <container port>
```

This is how ports are mapped in docker. So either change the host port in app or test to different port like below.

For app keep below ports:

```
7500:8000
```

Now your app will be accessible at port 7500 and test at 8000

Comment: what is the new error?

Comment: When I do this: <7500:8000> in the app container I can't connect to the server address and all tests crash with : < connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:8000> I can't deal with these ports and mapping between them

Comment: When I do this: <7500:8000> in the test container, only the tests are crashing with the same error above

Comment: When you do <7500:8000> in the app container , you need to know that, now your app is accessible only through port 7500. so in your testcases, check the api you are connecting to, you might have given 8000 port, you need to make it 7500

Comment: I know, but the interesting thing is that when i try to access it on my local machine at        ` http://0.0.0.0:7500/`  while app container is running it refuses the connection either, So I continue to digging

Comment: try 127.0.0.1:7500

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238317/discussion-between-htodev-and-liquiddeath).